# Convert alphanumeric string to numeric - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, alphanumeric

I have this alphanumeric string

```
000193CA020008AA190038AA
```

I want it to be a unique number, for example

```
123456791011121314151617.
```

Is there a way to do it on PLSQL?
Not all aphanumerics are the same length,  does not contain hex numbers only.

I have tried

```
create or replace FUNCTION FN_BOM_STEEL_CHAR_TO_NUMBER(
  value IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  c        CHAR(1);
  up_value VARCHAR2(5000) := LTRIM(UPPER(value),'0');
  total    NUMBER  := 0;
  len      PLS_INTEGER    := COALESCE(LENGTH(up_value),0);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. len LOOP
    c := SUBSTR(up_value,i,1);
    total := total * 36
                   + CASE
                     WHEN '0' <= c AND c <= '9'
                     THEN TO_NUMBER(c)
                     ELSE ASCII(c) - 55
                     END;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN total;
END FN_BOM_STEEL_CHAR_TO_NUMBER;
```

and it worked really well but I have just found there are some duplicates with different alphanumeric strings, for example

1. 010000AA000001AA020019AA020047AA020138AA020139AA0600**18**AA190016AA
2. 010000AA000001AA020019AA020047AA020138AA020139AA0600**19**AA190016AA

You can see there is a 18 and 19 that makes the difference on them but when I select the function I'm getting the same ID for both. There are more cases like these.

Here's the select I'm trying for those examples

```
SELECT FN_BOM_STEEL_CHAR_TO_NUMBER('010000AA000001AA020019AA020047AA020138AA020139AA060018AA190016AA
') AS ID
FROM   DUAL;
```

and this is the ID for both:
*3095673299759705115226102843045930360610000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*

I need them to be different.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible? Probably, if you tell us the algorithm which converts "source" to "target".

Comment: Can you show us some sample data with output, and the logic behind the said conversion?

Comment: Uniqueness depends on many conditions. Should it be unique during some time frame or for all the database's life? Should the same source string (or parts of it) be translated to the same result string (which is known as function)? Do source and target need to have any relation between them or result number may be any number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have the characters `0123456789ABCDEF` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT TO_NUMBER(
         '000193CA020008AA190038AA',
         'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
       ) AS from_hex_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> |            FROM_HEX_VALUE |
> | ------------------------: |
> | 1906840079024071083309226 |
> ```

If you have the characters `0-9A-Z` and want to treat it as a base 36 string then you could create the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION base36_to_number(
  value  IN VARCHAR2,
  -- The value to parse from base 36 to base 10.
  width  IN INT DEFAULT 0,
  -- The width of the substring to consider; 0 is the entire string.
  offset IN INT DEFAULT 0
  -- The number of widths to offset from the least-significant digit.
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  c         CHAR(1);
  total     NUMBER := 0;
  len       PLS_INTEGER    := COALESCE(LENGTH(value),0);
  start_pos PLS_INTEGER;
  end_pos   PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  IF width < 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Invalid width.' );
  ELSIF offset < 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20000, 'Invalid offset.' );
  ELSIF width = 0 THEN
    start_pos := 1;
    end_pos   := len;
  ELSIF width * offset > len THEN
    RETURN 0;
  ELSIF width * (offset + 1) > len THEN
    start_pos := 1;
    end_pos   := len - width  * offset;
  ELSE
    start_pos := len - width * ( offset + 1 ) + 1;
    end_pos   := start_pos + width - 1;
  END IF;

  FOR i IN start_pos .. end_pos LOOP
    c := SUBSTR(value,i,1);
    total := total * 36
                   + CASE
                     WHEN '0' <= c AND c <= '9'
                     THEN TO_NUMBER(c)
                     WHEN 'A' <= c AND c <= 'Z'
                     THEN ASCII(c) - 55
                     WHEN 'a' <= c AND c <= 'z'
                     THEN ASCII(c) - 87
                     ELSE NULL
                     END;
  END LOOP;
  
  total := total * POWER( 36, width * offset );
  RETURN total;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT BASE36_TO_NUMBER('000193CA020008AA190038AA') AS from_base36_value
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> |                FROM_BASE36_VALUE |
> | -------------------------------: |
> | 16743829188442650222733747166386 |
> ```

The maximum size of a `NUMBER` is 38 decimal digits and you cannot fit more than a 24 character base-36 number into this. If you have a larger value then you will need to convert it to multiple numbers:

I.e.:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT '010000AA000001AA020019AA020047AA020138AA020139AA060018AA190016AA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '010000AA000001AA020019AA020047AA020138AA020139AA060019AA190016AA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT BASE36_TO_NUMBER( value, 24, 0 ) AS low_value,
       BASE36_TO_NUMBER( value, 24, 1 ) AS mid_value,
       BASE36_TO_NUMBER( value, 24, 2 ) AS high_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>                              LOW_VALUE |                                                                   MID_VALUE |                                                                                           HIGH_VALUE
> -------------------------------------: | --------------------------------------------------------------------------: | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------:
>    34663123071664682325935025837090322 |    777948567801018784511679412336101916888000000000000000000000000000000000 |    3095673299759705115226102065097362559570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>    34663123071664682329591184277153298 |    777948567801018784511679412336101916888000000000000000000000000000000000 |    3095673299759705115226102065097362559570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 22452257707354557240087211123792674815 | 504103876157462118901767181449118688664000000000000000000000000000000000000 | 4011991914547630480065052883598567655228000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c0b264ac141b72807b6e53fe49aa6bd)*

Comment: what if not all alphanumerics are the same length because tried and it obviously didn't work out

SELECT TO_NUMBER(NUM_SEPARADOR, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ) AS ID_SEPARADOR
FROM tmp_bom_steel7;

I also tried 

SELECT TO_NUMBER(NUM_SEPARADOR) AS ID_SEPARADOR
FROM tmp_bom_steel7;

but keeps telling me wrong invalid number.
I'm a beginner, sorry for the simple questions

Comment: @RenataEsquivel If your column is a `VARCHAR2(50)` then use 50 `X` characters so that the format model is as long as the largest possible string value.

Comment: Also, if your column does not contain hex numbers only (this is digits and A-F letters only), you could make use of `dbms_crypto` and generate sha1 first. Sha1 is 40 characters long.

Comment: @KrzysztofKaszkowiak It is theoretically possible to have hash collisions (and they have been generated) so SHA1 may not meet the question's requirement for uniqueness (practically, you aren't likely to encounter a hash collision so that may be sufficient).

Comment: does not contain hex numbers only that's the reason of the error.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked @MT0 today learned something new. Greetings!

Comment: @MT0 I just edited the post I hope you can see what is happening now. Thanks!

Comment: @RenataEsquivel That is because your values are too big and, in Oracle, a `NUMBER` can only store up to 38 decimal digits and if you exceed that then precision will be lost. You need to split the string up into smaller sub-strings.